# Node.js Is there a way to convert timestamps to dates in a .csv file?

Tags: node.js, csv

I use C3-chart-maker to generate a chart from a .csv file, however I noticed that i can't use the one below as the "timestamp" column isn't the right format.

Is there a way to convert the values in "timestamp" to dates like "2020-05-25 12:15:00" ?

[image]

EDIT:

Here is my code as asked in comments

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const csv = require('fast-csv')
var moment = require('moment')
fs.createReadStream('./test.csv')
    .pipe(csv.parse({headers: true}))
    .on('error', error => console.error(error))
    .on('data', row => {
        console.log(row)
        var time = row['timestamp']
        let dataset = row_.each(dataset, function(x) => {dataset[x] = moment(new Date(x.time)).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
        })
    })
    .on('end', rowCount => console.log(`Parsed ${rowCount} rows`))
```

I tried implementing this line:

```
let dataset = row_.each(dataset, function(x) => 
{dataset[x] = moment(new Date(x.time)).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')})
```

However i get "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '=>'"

And here are some rows from my .csv file:

```
timestamp,latitude,longitude,niveau_eau,pression_eau,horametre_pompe,niv_huile,pression_huile,temperature_huile,boite_hydrostatique,rampe_gauche,rampe_droite,jet_avant_gauche,jet_avant_droite,jet_lateral_gauche,jet_lateral_droite,potence,lance,rampe_croisee_gauche,rampe_croisee_droite,rampe_saumure,aerorefroidisseur
43668.220659722225,nan,nan,8.5,-0.2,95.0,87.5,0.1,37.9,95.0,2.0,3.0,5.0,5.0,0.0,0.0,49.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0
43668.22100694444,48.819776,2.3898612,8.6,-0.2,95.0,87.5,-0.2,37.9,95.0,2.0,3.0,5.0,5.0,0.0,0.0,49.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0
43668.22168981482,48.8198016,2.3898386,8.6,-0.2,95.0,87.5,-0.2,37.9,95.0,2.0,3.0,5.0,5.0,0.0,0.0,49.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0
43668.222407407404,48.819856,2.3898572,8.6,-0.3,95.0,87.5,-0.2,37.9,95.0,2.0,3.0,5.0,5.0,0.0,0.0,49.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0
```

Comment: how about you just use moment and use format function to convert time to desired output?

Comment: I've tried to use format() as follow: var time = moment(row['timestamp']), then console.log(time.format()). However it says "invalid date", is there a specific function to use timestamps ?

Comment: can you paste your code?
Or maybe you can use underscore js and moment. Or maybe you don't even need to use underscorejs and only using moment can work.

you can check the code in below comment

Comment: let dataset = [
  { timestamp: 'xxxxxx', latitude: 'xxxxxxx', longitude: 'xxxxxx' },
  { timestamp: 'xxxxxx', latitude: 'xxxxxxx', longitude: 'xxxxxx' },
  { timestamp: 'xxxxxx', latitude: 'xxxxxxx', longitude: 'xxxxxx' }
]

_.each(dataset, function (x) => {
  dataset[x] = moment(new Date(x.timestamp)).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
})

console.log(dataset)

Comment: If this does not work can you send me some rows of your data set as a sample?

Comment: I've solved my problem by using toUTCString(), and I've realized that all my timestamps are from the 70's which is another problem. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

I also had the same problem, ***.toUTCString()*** helps me to resolve the same.

```
dataSet = dataSet.map(data => {
data.timestamp = data.timestamp.toUTCString();
return data;
})
```